# The type or namespace cannot be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, using-directives

I get the following error when I try to compile my C# program:

`The type or namespace name 'Login' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FootballLeague
{
    public partial class MainMenu : Form
    {
    FootballLeagueDatabase footballLeagueDatabase;
    Game game;
    Team team;
    Login login; //Error here

    public MainMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        changePanel(1);
    }

    public MainMenu(FootballLeagueDatabase footballLeagueDatabaseIn)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        footballLeagueDatabase = footballLeagueDatabaseIn;
    }

    private void Form_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void gameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int option = 0;
        changePanel(option);
    }
    private void scoreboardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int option = 1;
        changePanel(option);
    }
    private void changePanel(int optionIn)
    {
        gamePanel.Hide();
        scoreboardPanel.Hide();

        string title = "Football League System";

        switch (optionIn)
        {
            case 0:
                gamePanel.Show();
                this.Text = title + " - Game Menu";
                break;
            case 1:
                scoreboardPanel.Show();
                this.Text = title + " - Display Menu";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void logoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        login = new Login();
        login.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

#### `Login.cs` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FootballLeagueSystem
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
    MainMenu menu;
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void administratorLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username1 = "08247739";
        string password1 = "08247739";

        if ((userNameTxt.Text.Length) == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your username!");
        else if ((passwordTxt.Text.Length) == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your password!");
        else if (userNameTxt.Text.Equals("") || passwordTxt.Text.Equals(""))
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password!");
        else
        {
            if (this.userNameTxt.Text == username1 && this.passwordTxt.Text == password1)
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome Administrator!", "Administrator Login");
            menu = new MainMenu();
            menu.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }

    private void managerLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            string username2 = "1111";
            string password2 = "1111";

            if ((userNameTxt.Text.Length) == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your username!");
            else if ((passwordTxt.Text.Length) == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your password!");
            else if (userNameTxt.Text.Equals("") && passwordTxt.Text.Equals(""))
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password!");
            else
            {
                if (this.userNameTxt.Text == username2 && this.passwordTxt.Text == password2)
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome Manager!", "Manager Login");
                menu = new MainMenu();
                menu.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }

    private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    }
}
```

Where is the error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: These comments are a little uncalled for. Obviously, the asker is missing an assembly reference. The question was how to fix that problem as the error message doesn't clarify that.

Comment: Please check the link, it might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/40838955/3763015

Comment: Please refer the link, this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/40838955/3763015

Comment: What annoys me about this is that Visual Studio is unable to fix it. I am missing something that is used elsewhere in my solution. The suggested solutions should have an option to copy missing references from another project in the solution.

Comment: got same error & found out that `login.cs` app was in the same directory with the `FootballLeagueSystem` namespace app. Putting them separately fixed it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't have the namespace the Login class is in as a reference.

Add the following to the form that uses the `Login` class:

```
using FootballLeagueSystem;
```

When you want to use a class in another [namespace](http://www.codersource.net/microsoft-net/c-basics-tutorials/c-net-tutorial-namespaces.aspx), you have to tell the compiler where to find it. In this case, `Login` is inside the `FootballLeagueSystem` namespace, or : `FootballLeagueSystem.Login` is the *fully qualified namespace*.

As a commenter pointed out, you declare the Login class inside the `FootballLeagueSystem` namespace, but you're using it in the `FootballLeague` namespace.

Comment: Login is in the FootballLeagueSystem.
It should not be a fully qualified namespace.

Comment: Which is a different namespace than the one the form is in, so either you add the using directive, or you fully qualify the name. The error message is spot on.

Answer (score 50):

I get this error when my project .net framework version does not match the framework version of the DLL I am linking to. In my case, I was getting:

"The type or namespace name 'UserVoice' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

UserVoice was .Net 4.0, and my project properties were set to ".Net 4.0 Client Profile". Changing to .Net 4.0 on the project cleared the error. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks!  Once I read this I remembered running into it before, but I was pretty well stumped at first...

Comment: Spot on. This demonstrates that the comments pointing out "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" are not necessarily relevant. If you have actually _not_ done either of those, you should see the errors in your source _before_ compile time. If you have incompatible assemblies, you can go mad wondering why what looks _exactly_ like a properly declared assembly is not found in the compile.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a .net framework 4.8 project referencing a 4.6.1 targeted project. Switching the 4.6.1 project to target 4.8 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the following line:

```
using FootballLeagueSystem;
```

into your all your classes (MainMenu.cs, programme.cs, etc.) that use `Login`.

At the moment the compiler can't find the `Login` class.

Comment: I used this line to my MainMenu form, but I got same error in the programme.cs class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FoolballLeague
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new **Login());
        }
    }

**Login()); error shows here
}

Comment: So then you add the same using directive to program.cs. What is the problem here? Read the error message...

Comment: Or go into the properties of the project(s) in question and add it to the list of globally imported namespaces (if it's there).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Login in a seperate folder within your project make sure that where you are using it you do:

`using FootballLeagueSystem.[Whatever folder you are using]`

Comment: While that is true the clue is on his source code... i.e. the namespace for the login class is different from the main form.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because compile does not know where to find the class..so it occurs mainly when u copy or import item ..to solve this ..
1.change the namespace in the formname.cs and formname.designer.cs to the name of your project .