# Why am I getting error CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am using [Snarl C# API](https://github.com/TlhanGhun/Snarl-Network-Protocol-Csharp/blob/master/SnarlNetwork.cs) to send notifications to snarl.

Now I have saved the content of above url in a file named `SnarlNetwork.cs` and the content of my `test.cs` file are:

```
using SnarlNetworkProtocol;
using System;
class test
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        SNP snarl_object = new SNP();
        string hostname = "localhost";
        string hostport = "9887";
        string appName = "Spotify";

        bool val = snarl_object.register(hostname, hostport, appName);

        if (val == true)
        {
            string title = "hello";
            string message = "world";
            string timeout = "5";
            bool newval = snarl_object.notify(hostname, hostport, appName, null, title, message, timeout);

            if (newval == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("sucessfull");

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now when I try to compile my test.cs file using `csc test.cs` I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Noob\csharp>csc test.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler version 3.5.30729.4926
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 3.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

test.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SnarlNetworkProtocol' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So, what am I doing wrong here because according to me I am not missing any `using directive`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
C:\Users\Noob\csharp>csc test.cs
```

You haven't added a reference to the DLL. You need something like:

```
C:\Users\Noob\csharp>csc test.cs /r:SnarlNetwork.dll
```

(or whatever the assembly is called).

Alternatively, if you haven't got it as a separate library, just compile both files:

```
C:\Users\Noob\csharp>csc test.cs SnarlNetwork.cs
```

If you haven't compiled an assembly but *want* to, you can use:

```
csc /target:library /out:SnarlNetwork.dll SnarlNetwork.cs

csc Test.cs /r:SnarlNetwork.dll
```

(In fact, specifying the output file is unnecessary in this particular case, but it's still clearer...)

Comment: An extension to the question: how would one include a .dll file in a different directory? I've written the correct path: `/r:./bin/Debug/something.dll` but get an error saying "Source file 'r:etc' could not be found."

Comment: @Dagrooms: Are you sure you had the `/` in front? It should be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm positive. The /r option is having trouble referencing any file outside of the current directory.

Comment: @Dagrooms: I suggest you ask a new question with more details and a full example reproducing the problem then.

Comment: @JonSkeet: How can i add more than one assembly using /r?

Comment: @DmitryDronov: Use it twice: `/r:Assembly1.dll /r:Assembly2.dll`

Answer (score 47):

I was using **.NET Framework 4.5** but my new library had **.NET Framework 4.5.2** and I got the same issue when I tried to build. I solved it by updating my project from **4.5** to **4.5.2** (same as my library).

Answer (score 29):

1. On the ***Solution Explorer*** tab right click and select ***Properties***
2. Resolve this issue by updating the ***Target Framework*** in the project application settings.

For instance, In my case the project was compiling with .net framework version 4.5.1 but the dll which were referenced were compiled with the version 4.6.1.
So have updated the my project version. I hope it works for you.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Edit: Oh ignore me, you're not using Visual Studio.

Have you added the reference to your project?

As in this sort of thing:

[image]

Comment: This is still a useful answer for those of us less familiar with Visual Studio.

Comment: How can I add a reference manually, without Visual Studio? What text file I must to alter?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich I suggest asking a new question for that one

Answer (score 4):

It might be due to "client profile" of the .NET Framework.
Try to use the "full version" of .NET.

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens to me when I have a using statement but have forgotten to reference the assembly that defines the namespace.

But in your case, as the namespace is defined in a file in your project, you have forgotten to tell the compiler about the snarlnetwork.cs file.

See [csc compiler examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

Comment: There is no assembly just the `SnarlNetwork.cs` and `test.cs` file in my folder. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error on a MVC Project. And after a long research i found out that the .cs file containing some of the classes i referenced in the main project had a Build Actions set to "Content" ...

After changing it "Content"->"Compile" the error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

most of the problems cause by .NET Framework. So just go to project properties and change .Net version same as your reference dll.

Done!!!

Hope it's help :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: that's explain how problem happen and explain how to solve. is it does not make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by making sure my project shared the same .Net Framework version as the projects/libraries it depended on.

It turned out the libraries (projects within the solution) used .Net 4.6.1 and my project was using 4.5.2

Answer (score 1):

i also faced same problem,

**Reason**: why i faced this error is, 
rather then creating new partial view, 
i have created class and then renamed its extension from ".cs" to ".cshtml".

**Solution**: 
Just delete that rename view and re-create proper partial/full view. it will work fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Web.Config and find namespace = . you can remove or if you need it you must create new

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when used cs file was located inside project folder, but did not referenced from .csproj of parent project. 
Intellisence see this file inside project folder, but compiler does not see it  because of missing reference in .csproj

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by adding the reference to System.Web.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error due to a missing reference.
The reason I did not notice is because Resharper offers to add a using and a reference. Adding the using succeeds (but it's highlighted grey), syntax highlighting of missing classes works (sometimes), but adding the reference fails silently.

When manually adding the reference an error pops up, explaining why adding the reference fails (circular reference).  Resharper did not pass this error on to the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I clone my project from Git and directly build the solution first time. Instead of that go to the local repository in file explorer and double click the solution file (.sln) solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after first pulling and starting a new solution. It was fixed in visual studio by first cleaning the project. Then restoring the packages. When I built again, there were no more type or namespace errors.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if the the client framework is higher than the library framework client project builds successfully. So I suggest you check the Platform Target to make sure there is no conflicts.

*right mouse button project > Properties > Build* and uncheck **Prefer 32-bit** which is available for console project only. And check both projects target the same platform.
[[image: uncheck Prefer 32-bit1]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just "add refence" and browser the DLL file. it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I first cloned my project from Git to Visual Studio. I just had to update my NuGet packages, and then I was good to go!

Project > Manage NuGet Packages... >
Then update the packages. It notified me and there was a yellow bar with a button that I pushed and it downloaded the packages!