# "CS0246: namespace not found" error when referencing locally hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service hosted locally in IIS 7 that is accessible through a browser and also a website when running in IIS Express, on deploying the same website to IIS i am presented with the error:

"CS0246: The type or namespace name 'smsService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Everything I've come across would suggest there's probably something wrong in the web.config file(s) so I've listed their contents below.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Webservice:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_smsServiceContract" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:82/smsService/smsService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_smsServiceContract"
        contract="smsService.smsServiceContract" name="BasicHttpBinding_smsServiceContract" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Website:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_smsServiceContract" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:82/smsService/smsService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_smsServiceContract"
        contract="smsService.smsServiceContract" name="BasicHttpBinding_smsServiceContract" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854308/why-am-i-getting-error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found) help?

Comment: I've added the service reference in the web project and there's no .dll in the service to reference

Comment: Does the error appear during the publish to IIS or only when attempting to access the WCF service via the website that was deployed?

Comment: Only when attempting to load the website that was deployed