# Convert Website to Web application With Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-applications, web

I have a Website Solution and I want Convert it to Web Application.

When I Transfer Base files (like DAL,BLL(.cs files my mean)) and Build My Solution it's working.
But When I Add other files that use the Base Files I have Many Errors Like (CS0246,CS0103,CS0118,CS1061).

I see this answer like:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7xf6dxs.aspx

and

[Why am I getting error CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854308/why-am-i-getting-error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

I want to Know if I build My Solution and Visual Studio Create .dll files why I have error that say not found X.dll?  and how can it be fix?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go through and fix each error in turn as you migrate.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx

I usually create an empty Web Application project and then copy the output into the same folder as my Web Site. Then I open the web application project in tye same solution as my website. Now you have two Projects for the same location.

Now enable the "show hidden files" option and "include" all the files in your project. At this point you will get loads of errors... Make sure that you first right-click on the root of your Web Application and select "Upgrade to Web Application" as this will do much of the grunt work for you.

In Web Applications you get Partial classes and when generated they are clashing with each other. In a Web Site you can have duplicate namespaces and class names, in a web application you can't. You need to go through all of your *.aspx and it's associated files and rename all of the class snakes to be unique.

This will start removing the errors although it may take some time to get through them all.