# App_Code AppInitialize does not compile when dependencies within a sub directory of bin

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the following structure of an IIS application:

```
IIS Application\
  App_Code\
    AppInitializer.cs
  bin\
    CommonLibrary //junction folder
  ...
  foo.svc
  web.config
```

The AppInitializer.cs contains the following:

```
using CommonLibrary; //Dependency located inside the junction folder
namespace TD.Registry
{
  public class Hostbootstrapper
  {
    public static void AppInitialize()
    {
       //Some code here using CommonLibrary
    }
  }
}
```

When I browse the IIS application in the web browser it results in a Compilation Error with the following message

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CommonLibrary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't set the `CommonLibrary/myDll.dll` to copy over when you build the application.  You can right click the .dll file in visual studio (which I'm assuming you're using) and select "Copy When Newer" or "Copy Always" as the Build Action for that file.  Disclaimer:  It's been 8+ years since I've developed an oldschool ASP.Net app!

Comment: Hi Dan, the common library dlls exist inside the junction folder.

Comment: Will the project report an error when compiling? Did you not add the reference correctly?You can refer to this link, which contains solutions to similar problems:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854308/why-am-i-getting-error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found

Comment: The project does not report any error when compiling. Interestingly, it seems that the reference dlls are found when the AppInitializer.cs is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the compilation error by adding the needed assemblies in the `web.config` like so:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="CommonLibrary"/>
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  
  ...
  
</system.web>
```