# Cannot build project when multiple versions of Visual Studio exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I first installed Visual Studio 2022 for a project of mine. I was able to build that project successfully and run it / debug it.

I then proceeded to install Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition in both instances) to work with another **different project** of mine that was compatible with only 2019 version. However, I am facing build issues with this one. I have the following code:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

...
...
public static ServiceProvider foobar => ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider;
```

However, I get the following error during build:

```
CS0246: The type or namespace "ServiceProvider" could not be found (are you missing
directive or assembly reference)
```

Additionally, the editor also highlights the `using...` statement as `using directive is unnecessary` - but that's the one for the ServiceProvider. Can't make out why it is not being picked up.

I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854308/why-am-i-getting-error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found) question and the answers to it but it does not seem to be applicable in my case.

My project (the one that fails to build) needs 4.6.1 of the .Net framework - and I have 4.8.0 installed. Trying to install 4.6.1 tells me that I already have the latest version and the installation quits.

What could be the reason for this build error? Can't I work with both Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 editions for different project needs?

Comment: Maybe you will need to add a NuGet package for it: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0/

Comment: I support Matthew Watson on this CS0246 error. You can try to install the nuget package of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0. If you cannot install .net framework 4.6.1, what you need to download is not the runtime of framework4.6.1, but the development kit of framework4.6.1. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net461