# The type or namespace name `HolidayService2' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: dll, namespaces, mono, .net-core, monodevelop

On Linux, how do I compile and execute `holidayclient.cs`? A `using` import is [required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2721372/262852), of course.  Also a `namespace`?

```
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ 
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ ls
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ 
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ wsdl http://api.google.com/GoogleSearch.wsdl
Web Services Description Language Utility
Mono Framework v4.0.30319.42000
Error: ThereWasAnErrorDownloading0
Stack:
   at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.Download (System.String& url, System.String& contentType) [0x000b1] in <df933ee897464fb99338a340b9d5761d>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.DiscoverAny (System.String url) [0x0000f] in <df933ee897464fb99338a340b9d5761d>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol:DiscoverAny (string)
  at Mono.WebServices.Driver.Run (System.String[] args) [0x000f5] in <24b8cb9db67d4a19a4db9642439f119f>:0 
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ 
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ wsdl http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx
Web Services Description Language Utility
Mono Framework v4.0.30319.42000
Writing file 'HolidayService2.cs'
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ 
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ mcs /target:library HolidayService2.cs -r:System.Web.Services
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ 
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ ls
HolidayService2.cs  HolidayService2.dll
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ 
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ nano holidayclient.cs
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ 
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ cat holidayclient.cs 
using System;

class HolidayClient
{
    public static void Main (string [] args)
    {
        HolidayService2 holiday = new HolidayService2 ();

        String response = holiday.foo ("hmm");

        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ 
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$ mcs holidayclient.cs 
holidayclient.cs(7,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HolidayService2' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
holidayclient.cs(9,27): error CS0841: A local variable `holiday' cannot be used before it is declared
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
thufir@dur:~/wsdl$
```

wasn't sure which buttons to click in `MonoDevelop` so was using the CLI.

references:

http://www.mono-project.com/archived/consuming_a_webservice/

http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?op=GetHolidayDate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246

Comment: Hey, could you give some context as to what you’re wanting to achieve? Are you wanting to add a reference to a web service and call it?

Comment: add a reference to the compiled dll which is a web service and then call a method on the library.  yes @muszeo.  Either CLI or monodevelop (Linux).

Comment: ok, I'm with you. Once you've generated the service client dll (HolidayService2.dll) then you should in theory be able to add it as a reference to your project in MonoDevelop and call it; this would be via the <project> / References  right-click  Edit References... dialogue  .NET Assembly tab. I'll write an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In MonoDevelop (MD) you'll need to create a new project of the type you are wanting (forms, console, web etc), and add your HolidayClient.cs code to it. You'll need to make sure the namespaces in your code align with those in the project, to keep things simple. Add a reference to the HolidayService.dll assembly using MD (right click on Project / References and select "Edit References..." then find the .NET Assembly tab and follow your nose to browse for it and load the reference). Once this is done you should be able to call the service client in your code.